# Batch File to find duplicate files and put them in separate directory

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have two directory on a Network drive . X:\MAPS and X:\MAPS2
Directory 1 and 2 have a bunch of files.

I need a batch file that will:
Read each file in Directory 1 and checks, if same file exists in Directory 2 then copy this file to a different Directory X:\MAPS3
Read the next file, and so on..
At the end, I end up have X:\MAPS3 which has only the duplicate files from 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%F in (X:\MAPS\*) do if exist "X:\MAPS2\%%~nxF" copy "%%~fF" "X:\MAPS3\%%~nxF"
```

**Extended Answer for Comment**

```
for %%F in (X:\MAPS\*) do (
    if exist "X:\MAPS2\%%~nxF" copy "%%~fF" "X:\MAPS3\%%~nxF"
    if exist "X:\MAPS5\%%~nxF" copy "%%~fF" "X:\MAPS3\%%~nxF"
    if exist "X:\MAPS7\%%~nxF" copy "%%~fF" "X:\MAPS3\%%~nxF"
    if exist "X:\MAPS8\%%~nxF" copy "%%~fF" "X:\MAPS3\%%~nxF"
    if exist "X:\MAPS9\%%~nxF" copy "%%~fF" "X:\MAPS3\%%~nxF"
)
```

Comment: I need to extend this to more than 1 directory...How would I go about that... for example X:\MAPS2,5,7,8,9.... Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part do you want to extend?  Do you want it to loop through each of those directories?  Or just check for the existence of the file in each of those directories?

Comment: just check for the existence of the file in each of those directories

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file:

```
cd /d X:\MAPS
for %%i in (*.*) do if exist "X:\MAPS2\%%1" copy "%%i" X:\MAPS3
```

From a command prompt:

```
C:>cd /d X:\MAPS
X:\MAPS>for %i in (*.*) do if exist "X:\MAPS2\%i" copy "%i" X:\MAPS3
```